# How to apply different corner radius to different corners of UIView in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cornerradius

I want to apply different corner radius value to different corners of `UIView` in `iOS` using `swift`. It means `topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight` corners of `UIView` should have **different** `corner radiuous`(i.e 1, 5, 10, 15). How can be implement it?

I tried applying cornerRadius in same way but It overrides the previous cornerRadius values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set cornerRadius for only top-left and top-right corner of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167266/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-top-left-and-top-right-corner-of-a-uiview)

Comment: You can also go through [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/rounded-corners-uiview/)

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237863/how-to-control-an-uiviews-rounded-corners-separately-using-ibinspectable-in-sw/45245114#45245114

Comment: @ShamasS I tried that but when I apply cornerRadius to topLeft and topRight first with radius 5. then apply radius 10 to bottomLeft and bottomRight. in that case apply changes got overridden. Can I not provide different radious values to different corners?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Thanks. This what I was looking for. At least, I got gist from it.

Answer (score 0):

If your **deployment target is abouve iOS 10** then you should use **maskedCorners**

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    customeView.clipsToBounds = true
    customeView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    customeView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMinYCorner]
}
```

else try this

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: customeView.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
            let mask = CAShapeLayer()
            mask.path = path.cgPath
            customeView.layer.mask = mask
```

Comment: This doesn't work, since it only allows the corners to be rounded to one value or not rounded at all. The original poster wanted different corners rounded to different degrees.